# Why despite a service being successfully deployed to Cloud Run, I can not access it and get a 404 response instead?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, deployment, devops, google-cloud-run

I have a Dockerfile with a service that I can successfully run locally and when I deploy it to Google Cloud with Cloud Run everything seems to work as well as there are no errors, but when I make a request to a url that should exist I get back 404.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
RUN npm ci --only=production

CMD node ./dist/index.js
```

The 2 commands I use to deploy my service are

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/{project-id}/backend-version-1.0.0 .

gcloud run deploy test-gcp-deploy --image gcr.io/{project-id}/backend-version-1.0.0 --region europe-west3 --platform managed --allow-unauthenticated --quiet --max-instances 2
```

My Typescript code contains this part

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 800;

...

app.get( "/healthz", ( req, res ) => {
   res.send( { status: 'running'} );
} );

app.listen( port, () => {
    console.log( `server started at http://localhost:${ port }` );
} );
```

My Cloud run service logs contain the following lines after one unsuccessful navigation to the url of the service that is auto generated.

```
2022-02-01T22:07:18.800340Z server started at http://localhost:8080
2022-02-01T22:07:25.301169Z Cloud Run test-gcp-deploy {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, resourceName: namespaces/{project-id}/services/test-gcp-deploy, response: {…}, serviceName: run.googleapis.com, status: {…}}
2022-02-01T22:07:48.659515Z GET 404 945 B 12ms Chrome 97 https://{service-url}
```

I added the logs in addition to the code as a proof that the environment variable PORT reaches my service as the port is 8080 instead of the default 800.

I have tried the urls

```
https://{service-url} => resolves to => Cannot GET /
https://{service-url}/healthz => resolves to => 404. That’s an error.The requested URL /healthz was not found on this server.
https://{service-url}:8080 => resolves to => This site can’t be reached
https://{service-url}:8080/healthz => resolves to => This site can’t be reached
```

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?
I am happy to provide any additional information if that would help you answer my question.

Comment: What URL are you using? Without details, we can only guess.

Comment: Cloud Run endpoints are only accessible on the `https` default port (443). So, the `:8080` examples won't work. The "/" GET shouldn't work either as you've no handler listening to the root. The only unexplained route is `https://{service-url}/healthz` which ought to work. To @john-hanley comment, are you confident you're using the correct service endpoint? Have you tried running the container locally?

Comment: {service-url} is the url that Cloud run generates automatically for a service. It is displayed with the copy icon next to it.

Comment: Also the first comment in my post says that it worked locally without any  problems.

Comment: I do also have a cloudbuild.yml in the project root, but I think it would not be used in the way I am deploying my app. If that is not the case, then I can provide the code in it as well.

Comment: any success on this? similar problems here with `Cannot GET /` as the response. not sure even what log files to look in for a rev-proxy or something upstream of my app.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Run, better to use the default port 8080, and in Dockerfile you need to expose the port before the last line.